Zoom webhooks validation in Node
EDIT:
If i use NGROK on my server, i can actually verify the endpoint.
What in the world is going on here lol. IS it because im using CERTBOT? is that not a trusted certificate authority?
im working on a webhook to take in finished webinar recordings.
I have followed the steps mentioned on the Zoom Docs and i have even copied the code directly from their example for Node. I can verify that my code is correctly hashing the token and is setting the correct information in the JSON object. Once again this is taken directly from the example from Zoom Docs. However when i try to verify, it doesnt work. Yes the site is live, with https, and the ENV variables are live as well. If anyone can help, i can provide the endpoint for you to test as well.
router.post("/verify", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Video Completed");
  try {
    console.log(req.body.payload.plainToken);

    const token = crypto
      .createHmac("sha256", process.env.ZOOM_APP_TOKEN)
      .update(req.body.payload.plainToken)
      .digest("hex");

    console.log(token);

    res.status(200);
    res.json({
      plainToken: req.body.payload.plainToken,
      encryptedToken: token,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});


"However when i try to verify, it doesnt work."  "Doesn't work" is not an accurate problem description. You say your code is correctly hashing and and setting the correct information into the json. So what exactly is "not working"?

zoom does not verify the link afterwards. I actually have a support call in with them now to address the issue. This may be a problem on their side

@derpirscher please see the edit

Well are you sure, your backend uses a valid certificate? Certbot per se is not a CA at all, it's just a tool for automatically requesting a certificate from any CA supporting the ACME protocol (typically it requests let's encrypt). But your backend then of course has to correctly use this certificate. Can you try checking your backend's (without ngrok) certificate with something like https://www.ssl.org

@derpirscher yea everything checks out. The website (and backend) is medspanetwork.com . Im wondering if centos or nginx or something is messing with the headers?

couldnt remember "let's encrypt" thats why i wrote certbot lol

So i restarted Nginx and now everything works lol.
